# Не работает import

Tags: python, discord.py

Здраствуйте! Я пишу ботов для дискорда и у меня всё работет.НО при дописание функции для бота по непонятной ошибке код не работает... КАК ИСПРАВИТЬ?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils
import time

from config import settings

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'm/')
p1 = 0
p2 = 1
p3 = 2
p4 = 3
p5 = 4
p6 = 5
p7 = 20

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print("[log] Подключено...")
#Лог
    await client.change_presence( status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game( 'm/help' ))
```

дальше идёт код тоже

Comment: пожалуйста дайте код текстом а не картинкой

Comment: @Danis я сделал код текстом

Comment: Так что у вас работает, а что нет?

Comment: неработает пишет в начале synctic error и указывает на  import

Comment: Вы можете скопировать и показать текст ошибки?

Comment: @SergBocharov https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqN4H.jpg

Comment: Я исправил проблема была в if который ыл в коде

Answer (score 0):

Будем сичтать, что демонстрация какой-то картинки без привязки к экрану программы и самому коду -  это не троллинг, а от неопытности.

Может все-таки в коде надо писать

```
from discord_config import Settings
```